# Change file members when creating RPM updates

Tags: rpmbuild, rpm-spec

Our application has been packaged into a single rpm file for the past few years with the usual numbered updates.  Now I'd like to separate out some of the files into a second RPM for product management purposes.

Is the correct way to just remove the files from the `%files` section of the old `.spec` file and add them to the new `.spec` file?

For example, we now have `myApp.rpm` built from:

```
/usr/local/myApp
+ bin/ {bunch of files here}
+ config/ {bunch of files here}
+ branding/
```

So the current spec file lists everything above in its `%files` directive.

To split `branding` into a separate rpm without messing up packaging?  eg.

**myApp.spec**

```
Name: myApp
%install
  {make directories, copy everything but branding}
%files
/%{_prefix}/myApp
/%{_prefix}/myApp/bin/*
/%{_prefix}/myApp/config/*
```

and

**branding.spec**

```
Name: myApp_branding
Requires: myApp
%install
   {copy branding to rpm tree}
%files
/%{_prefix}/myApp/branding/*
```

When existing installations are upgraded, will the package membership of the branding files be now be the `myApp_branding` package?

Any downsides or risks to this approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not recommended way.

Remember only one .spec file is enough for each project, you can use `%package` body item for additional rpm packages. for example add following code after meta information. i.e before `%prep` or `%build` items

```
%package branding
Summary: Branding for myApp
Requires: myApp
%description branding
branding files for myApp
```

After that, yes you can use multiple '%files' section for each package. like

```
%files
/%{_prefix}/myApp/bin/*
/%{_prefix}/myApp/config/*

%files branding
/%{_prefix}/myApp/branding/*
```

As you can see I have omitted `/%{_prefix}/myApp` line from main %files section. Actually when you pick a parent directory it automatically includes all its children, And when a sub package try to include child directory again, it will result in duplication error at build time. If you want to use `/%{_prefix}/myApp` then `%exclude` can help. see

```
%files
/%{_prefix}/myApp/*
%exclude /%{_prefix}/myApp/branding/*

%files branding
/%{_prefix}/myApp/branding/*
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but there will be several branding rpms for different white-label OEM branding skins.  So to each OEM partner we distribute ZIP files with (`myApp.rpm brandingA.rpm`) and (`myApp.rpm brandingB.rpm`), (`myApp.rpm brandingC.rpm`) etc. Previously the (single set of) branding files were within `myApp.rpm`.  I'm trying to confirm whether the package ownership of the files previously in `myApp.rpm` are properly re-assigned to `brandingX`.rpm ...

Comment: That is ok to create multiple branding rpms. and then delivering selected brand in zip. However In case your brands / themes share same destination / directory, then you can address this problem in `%post brandingX` section by adding symlinks like `%{__ln_s} /usr/myApp/brandingX /usr/myApp/defaultBrand`

Comment: Anything mentioned under `%files brandingX` will be ownered by same package, just remember to exclude it from main `%files` section either omitting parent directory or via `%exclude`